# Matlab - vpasolve error when solving system of equations

Tags: matlab

I'm currently trying to solve a system of equations, where `h2, eta, B, U` are known but I have left them as symbolic variables for now:

```
clearvars
clc

syms x x0 h0 h1 h2 C2 eta B U

h(x) = h0 + h2*(x/(B/2))^2;

h_bar(x) = h(x)/h0;
hc_bar = 1+(h2/h0)*(x0/(B/2))^2;
x_bar(x) = x/(B/2);
x0_bar = x_bar(x0);

integration = int(((h_bar^2-hc_bar^2)/(h_bar^3)),x);

p(x) = ((3*eta*U*B)/(h0^2))*integration+C2;
p_d(x) = diff(p(x),x);

p_fun1 = p(x0_bar) == 0;
p_fun2 = p_d(x0_bar) == 0;
p_fun3 = p(-1) == 0;
p_fun4 = h1-h0 == h2;
```

Four equations, four unknowns so I should be able to solve this. However the system of equations is a bit overwhelming so I decided to try my luck with `vpasolve`:

```
vpasolve([p_fun1, p_fun2, p_fun3, p_fun4],[x0, h0, h1, C2])
```

This results in the following error:

```
Error using mupadengine/feval (line 166)
Symbolic parameters are not allowed in nonpolynomial equations.

Error in sym/vpasolve (line 172)
    sol = eng.feval('symobj::vpasolve',eqns,vars,X0);

Error in Yke (line 35)
vpasolve([p_fun1, p_fun2, p_fun3, p_fun4],[x0, h0, h1, C2])
```

I have traced the error back to `p_fun1` specifically, but I cannot see why this specific function would trigger the error. It is complicated, but `p_fun2` is the derivative of `p_fun1` and `p_fun3` is simply `p_fun1` with a different value substituted in the equation, yet these do not trigger the error.

I'm pretty sure the error is caused by replacing `x` with `x_bar` in the `p_fun1 = p(x0_bar) == 0` call, but I don't know why and therefore I also don't know how to solve it. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong at the moment?

Comment: `vpasolve` is a numerical solver, you cannot have symbolic parameters in the equations.

Comment: So what you're saying is; instead of leaving the other symbolic values in the equation I should substitute all the symbolic values with their real numbers? (except for `x0, h0, h1, C2` of course)

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I mean.

Comment: You should post it as an answer so I can accept it and close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`vpasolve`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpasolve.html) is a numerical solver (in fact, *vpa* stands for *variable-precision arithmetic*), and you cannot have symbolic parameters in the equations.

You should thus substitute numerical values to all the equation parameters.

Comment: I am confused, all examples under vpasolve Matlab help have symbolic parameters.

Comment: @Millemila No, they don't. The unknown(s) are symbolic, but all the coefficients are numeric.

Comment: So if I have a variable that is numeric, but written as $x$, what should I do instead?

In my case I tried to use vpasolve to solve an equation following this:

vpasolve( constant == x.^2 , x , 1.5) where 1.5 is my rough guess of the variable, "x". 
Why do I get this same error message.